# Python RobotFileParser hangs in read

Tags: python-3.x, robots.txt

I am trying to read the robots.txt file and figure out if the bot is allowed to read a specific page.

```
import urllib.robotparser as urobot
import urllib.request

url = "https://example.com"
rp = urobot.RobotFileParser()
rp.set_url(url + "/robots.txt")
rp.read()
if rp.can_fetch("*", URL):
    #do something
else:
    # else do something
```

While the above program runs fine for most URLs, it hangs for a couple of them at **rp.read()**

it just hangs at read() and does not throw any exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to source code of `read()` function it primarily consist of 2 methods: `urllib.request.urlopen(self.url)` and read of this content.

So looks like it could "hangs" in 2 ways — when making request / waiting response and when read and parse it content.

Due to content of robots.txt is usually small, then parsing is not a problem.

So the most possible case is request/response doing long.
You can check it in your browser in developer-tool which stage "hangs" the most.

You will see something like that: [network request phases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ym3x8.png) (timing phases [explained](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/reference?utm_source=devtools#timing-explanation))

---

One way to handle hanging connections is try to set default timeout:

```py
import urllib.robotparser as urobot
import socket

socket.setdefaulttimeout(1) # in seconds (float)

url = "https://example.com"
rp = urobot.RobotFileParser()
rp.set_url(url + "/robots.txt")
x = rp.read()
```

Comment: The browser is able to load the robots.txt file. It hangs while reading through the bot, I understand the network issues but since I don't have a handle over what is going on. I am not sure how to handle such scenario. Any idea how to gracefully handle this?

Comment: @AmitSingh probably setting default timeout could help with hanging connections. I updated post-answer with example of setting timeout. (i didn't test it on hanging connection, but I hope it should work). If you share some hanging links , I could test with them